# Firefox: Prevent itunes.apple.com from redirecting to itmss:

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, itunes, protocol

[itunes.apple.com](https://itunes.apple.com/app/wiki-triip-worldwide-offline/id667205846?ls=1&mt=8) shows its web page for 1 second before redirecting to a `itmss:` URL, which fails if iTunes is not installed. In a astonishing display of non-interoperability, Apple makes their web site unreadable for most of the world.

I don't want to install iTunes, I just want to read the web page.

A trick is to take a screenshot during that 1 second and read the screenshot, but it does not work if the web page is long.
Is there any better trick?

*Ubuntu 2013.04 Firefox 26.0*

Comment: Perhaps try another browser? I just tested that link out in IE and Firefox, with success. I do get a popup asking if I would like to install ITunes, but the page remains available to read after I click cancel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed it by disabling iTunes Application Detector plugin.

That plugin tries to emulate some features of iTunes using Rhythmbox, but as far as I know Rhythmbox doesn't support app stores yet.